# VBA Group Properties by Street Name

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a piece of code that loops over a range, and checks if the cell above matches the current cell.

When it finds a different cell above the current, insert a row, and add the street name to column "A", then continue.

The problem I am having is it take a while for it to process, can you suggest a different method.

Here is the code I am currently using.

```
headingRange = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, lastCol + 2).End(xlUp).Row
For headingID = headingRange To 7 Step -1
    lookupval = wb.SCAA.cells(headingID, lastCol + 2)
    With cells(headingID, lastCol + 2)
        If lookupval <> .Offset(-1) Then
            .EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
            With cells(headingID, 1)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .Font.bold = True
                .Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
                .IndentLevel = 0
            End With
        cells(headingID, 1) = wb.SCAA.cells(headingID + 1, lastCol + 2)
        End If
    End With
Next headingID
```

Here is an example screen shot of the data that I am trying to process.

[image: Exmple before grouping]

This is how the data should look after being grouped.

[image: Example after grouping]

As Requested, here is the whole sub.

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim lastRowWIR, lastRowPH, lastRowCODES, lastRow, lastCol As Long
Dim address, worktypeHeading, worktype_Valuation, headingID, headingRange, i As Long
Dim add_range_PH As Range, wID_range_PH As Range, sum_range_PH, sub_range_PH As Range
Dim add_range As Range, wID_range As Range, sum_range, sub_range As Range
Dim RangeCodes, RangeWIR, RangePH
Dim contract_total As Integer
Dim myRange As Range
Dim accountCode As Object: Set accountCode = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim CodeList As Object: Set CodeList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim addressList As Object: Set addressList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim addressAFA As Object: Set addressAFA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim addressValuation As Object: Set addressValuation = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim addressValuationTotal As Object: Set addressValuationTotal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim ContractList As Object: Set ContractList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim PHElementTotal As Object: Set PHElementTotal = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'''' TEST IF THE WORKS INSTRUCTION RECORD AND PAYMENT HISTORY HAVE FILTERS APPLIED, IF TRUE THEN REMOVE THEM
If wb.WIR.FilterMode = True Then wb.WIR.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
If wb.PH.FilterMode = True Then wb.PH.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

'''' CALL THE PROGRESS USERFORM SUBROUTINE
Call UserFrmProgressSub("Currently Producing Statement for: " & wb.SCAA.cells(2, 2).value, False)

'''' DO THE FIRST DEFINE FOR LAST ROWS IN DIFFERENT SHEETS, AND LAST COLUMN
lastCol = wb.SCAA.cells(6, columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRowWIR = wb.WIR.cells(Rows.count, WIR_AccountWorktypeID).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowPH = wb.PH.cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowCODES = wb.CODES.cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

'''' SET THE RANGE FOR THE EMAILIST DICTIOANARY CREATION
RangePH = wb.PH.Range("C2:H" & lastRowPH).value
RangeCodes = wb.CODES.Range("F3:G" & lastRowCODES).value
RangeWIR = wb.WIR.Range(wb.WIR.cells(3, WIR_AddressCode), wb.WIR.cells(lastRowWIR, WIR_ULRecharge)).value

'''' CREATE A SCRIPTING DICTIONARY TO HOLD THE ACCOUNT CODES (KEY:C, VALUE:CYCLICAL)
For i = LBound(RangeCodes) To UBound(RangeCodes, 1)
    '''' IF THE SUBCONTRACTOR IS NOT IN THE DICTIONARY THEN ADD IT
    If Not accountCode.exists(RangeCodes(i, 1)) Then accountCode.add RangeCodes(i, 1), RangeCodes(i, 2)
Next i

'''' CRAEATE MULTIPLE DICTIONARYS FROM THE WORKS INSTRUCTION RECORD
For i = LBound(RangeWIR) To UBound(RangeWIR, WIR_AddressCode)
    '''' ONLY ADD ITEMS TO THE RELEVANT DICTONARY IF THE SUBCONTRACTOR MATCHES THE SELECTED
    If RangeWIR(i, WIR_SubContractor) = cells(2, 2) Then
        '''' PRODUCE A CODE LIST FROM THE WIR BASED ON THE ACCOUNT WORKTYPE ID, THEN GET THE MATCHING VALUE FROM THE ACCONTCODE LIST KEYS FROM WIR, VALUE FROM CODELIST(KEY:L, VALUE:LIFECYLCE)
        If Not CodeList.exists(RangeWIR(i, WIR_AccountWorktypeID)) Then CodeList.add RangeWIR(i, WIR_AccountWorktypeID), accountCode(RangeWIR(i, WIR_AccountWorktypeID))
        '''' CREATE AND ADDRESS LIST WITH THE ADDRESS AS THE KEY, CONTACT, STREET AND PROPERTY NUMBER MAKE UP THE VALUE
        If Not addressList.exists(RangeWIR(i, WIR_AddressCode)) Then addressList.add RangeWIR(i, WIR_AddressCode), RangeWIR(i, WIR_Contract) & "|" & RangeWIR(i, WIR_Street) & "|" & Left(RangeWIR(i, WIR_AddressCode), InStr(RangeWIR(i, WIR_AddressCode), " "))
        '''' CREATE A DICTIONARY FOR THE CONTRACTS, EITHER PFI1, PFI2 OR BOTH
        If Not ContractList.exists(RangeWIR(i, WIR_Contract)) Then ContractList.add RangeWIR(i, WIR_Contract), RangeWIR(i, WIR_Contract)
        '''' DEFINE THE KEYS USED FOR THE ADDRESSAFA DICTONARY ADDRESS AND ACCOUNTWORKTYPE (14 ALMORAH ROAD|CYCLICAL)
        key = RangeWIR(i, WIR_AddressCode) & "|" & CodeList(RangeWIR(i, WIR_AccountWorktypeID))
        '''' THE ADDRESSAFA IS THE KEY AND THE RML ORDER VALUE FOR THAT ADDRESS AND CODE
        If Not addressAFA.exists(key) Then '''' IF THAT KEY IS NOT ALREADY IN THE DICTIONARY THE ADD IT WITH THE VALE
            addressAFA.add key, Round(RangeWIR(i, WIR_RMLOrderValue), 2)
        Else    '''' IF THE KEY IS IN THE DICTIONATY THE ADD THE NEW VALUE WITH WHATS ALREADY IN THE DICTIONARY
            addressAFA(key) = addressAFA(key) + Round(RangeWIR(i, WIR_RMLOrderValue), 2)
        End If
    End If
Next i

'''' CRAEATE MULTIPLE DICTIONARYS FROM THE PAYMENT HISTORY
For i = LBound(RangePH) To UBound(RangePH, 1)
    If RangePH(i, 2) = cells(2, 2) Then
        key = RangePH(i, 1) & "|" & CodeList(RangePH(i, 3))
        '''' TOTAL VALUE FOR ADDRESS & ELEMTENT (CYCLICAL)
        If Not addressValuation.exists(key) Then
            addressValuation.add key, Round(RangePH(i, 6), 2)
        Else
            addressValuation(key) = addressValuation(key) + Round(RangePH(i, 6), 2)
        End If
        '''' TOTAL VALUE FOR ADDRESS
        If Not addressValuationTotal.exists(RangePH(i, 1)) Then
            addressValuationTotal.add RangePH(i, 1), Round(RangePH(i, 6), 2)
        Else
            addressValuationTotal(RangePH(i, 1)) = addressValuationTotal(RangePH(i, 1)) + Round(RangePH(i, 6), 2)
        End If
        '''' PRODUCE A CODE LIST FROM THE WIR BASED ON THE ACCOUNT WORKTYPE ID, THEN GET THE MATCHING VALUE FROM THE ACCONTCODE LIST KEYS FROM WIR, VALUE FROM CODELIST(KEY:L, VALUE:LIFECYLCE)
        If Not PHElementTotal.exists(accountCode(RangePH(i, 3))) Then
            PHElementTotal.add accountCode(RangePH(i, 3)), Round(RangePH(i, 6), 2)
        Else
            PHElementTotal(accountCode(RangePH(i, 3))) = PHElementTotal(accountCode(RangePH(i, 3))) + Round(RangePH(i, 6), 2)
        End If
        If Not PHElementTotal.exists("Total") Then
            PHElementTotal.add "Total", Round(RangePH(i, 6), 2)
        Else
            PHElementTotal("Total") = PHElementTotal("Total") + Round(RangePH(i, 6), 2)
        End If
    End If
Next i

'''' SET THE ACCOUNTCODE DICTIONATY TO NOTHING TO FREE MEMORY (NOT USED AGAIN IN ROUTINE)
Set accountCode = Nothing

'''' TEST IF THE CODELIST HAS A COUNT OF 0, IF TRUE THE SUBCONTRACTO HAD NO WORK ISSUED TO THEN AND NOTHING PAID TO THEN. EXIT THE SUB
If CodeList.count = "0" Then
    MsgBox wb.SCAA.cells(2, 2).value & " has had no works issued to them." & vbLf & "A statement cannot be produced!", vbCritical, "SubContractor Statement Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

'''' CLEAR THE SHEET BEFORE STARTING
wb.SCAA.Rows("4:" & wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row + 10).Clear

'''' CALL THE SUBROUTINE TO CREATE THE SHEET HEADINGS
Call createSCAccountHeadings1(CodeList.count, CodeList)

'''' REDEFINE THE LAST COLUMN AFTER THE HEADINGS HAVE BEEN CREATED
lastCol = wb.SCAA.cells(6, columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'''' LOOP OVER THE ADDRESS LIST, AND SPLIT THE ITEM, TO ADD THE ADDRESS, PFI, PROPERTY NUMBER AND STREET TO SHEET
tableStart = 7
For Each key In addressList.keys
    wb.SCAA.cells(tableStart, 1) = key
    wb.SCAA.cells(tableStart, 2) = Split(addressList(key), "|")(0)
    wb.SCAA.cells(tableStart, lastCol + 2) = Split(addressList(key), "|")(1)
    wb.SCAA.cells(tableStart, lastCol + 1) = Split(addressList(key), "|")(2)
    tableStart = tableStart + 1
Next key

'''' DEFINE THE LASTROW
lastRow = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'''' APPLY INDENTS TO THE ADDRESS'S AND AUTOFIT COLUMN 1
wb.SCAA.Range("A7:A" & lastRow).InsertIndent 2
wb.SCAA.columns(1).AutoFit

'''' SET THE RANGES IN FOR THE SUM IF FUNCTIONS USED.
Set add_range = wb.WIR.columns(WIR_AddressCode)
Set wID_range = wb.WIR.columns(WIR_AccountWorktypeID)
Set sub_range = wb.WIR.columns(WIR_SubContractor)
Set sum_range = wb.WIR.columns(WIR_RMLOrderValue)
Set add_range_PH = wb.PH.Range("C:C")
Set wID_range_PH = wb.PH.Range("E:E")
Set sub_range_PH = wb.PH.Range("D:D")
Set sum_range_PH = wb.PH.Range("H:H")

'''' DEFINE MYRANGE
Set myRange = Range(cells(3, 1), cells(lastRow, lastCol))

'''' LOOP OVER THE ADDRESS AND WORKTYPE(COLUMNS), AND ADD VALUES AND FORMULAS
For address = 7 To lastRow
addressIns = wb.SCAA.cells(address, 1).value
    For worktypeHeading = 3 To myRange.columns.count
    Set wtHeading = wb.SCAA.cells(6, worktypeHeading)
        Select Case True
            Case worktypeHeading - 2 <= CodeList.count
                If IsEmpty(addressAFA(addressIns & "|" & wtHeading)) Then
                    wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading) = 0
                Else
                    wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading) = Format(addressAFA(addressIns & "|" & wtHeading), "Standard")
                End If
                wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
            Case worktypeHeading - 2 = CodeList.count + 1
                wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading).value = Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(cells(address, 3), cells(address, worktypeHeading - 1))), 2)
                wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
            Case worktypeHeading - 2 = CodeList.count + 2
                If cells(address, worktypeHeading - 1) = "0" And (addressValuationTotal(addressIns) = "0" Or IsEmpty(addressValuationTotal(addressIns))) Then
                    wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading).value = "0"
                Else
                    wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading).value = addressValuationTotal(addressIns) / cells(address, worktypeHeading - 1)
                End If
                wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                wb.SCAA.cells(address, "AAA").value = wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading)
                wb.SCAA.columns(worktypeHeading).AutoFit
            Case worktypeHeading - 2 > CodeList.count And worktypeHeading - 2 < myRange.columns.count - 2
                If IsEmpty(addressValuation(addressIns & "|" & wtHeading)) Then
                    totalValuation = 0
                Else
                    totalValuation = addressValuation(addressIns & "|" & wtHeading)
                End If
                myformula = "=Round(IF(" & cells(address, (worktypeHeading - (CodeList.count + 2))).address(False, False) & "=" & totalValuation & "," & totalValuation & "," & "SUM(" & cells(address, (worktypeHeading - (CodeList.count + 2))).address(False, False) & "*" & cells(address, CodeList.count + 4).address(False, False) & ")),2)"
                wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading).formula = myformula
                wb.SCAA.cells(address, worktypeHeading).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
            Case worktypeHeading - 2 = myRange.columns.count - 2
                wb.SCAA.cells(address, lastCol).formula = "=round(sum(" & cells(address, 5 + CodeList.count).address(False, False) & ":" & cells(address, worktypeHeading - 1).address(False, False) & "),2)"
                wb.SCAA.cells(address, lastCol).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
        End Select
    Next worktypeHeading
Next address

'''' SET THE BELOW SCRIPTING DICTIONARYS TO NOTHING, TO FREE MEMORY
Set addressList = Nothing
Set addressAFA = Nothing
Set addressValuation = Nothing
Set addressValuationTotal = Nothing

'''' REDEFINE THE LAST ROW
lastRow = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'''' TRANSPOSE THE CONTRACT LIST ON TO THE SHEET UNDER THE ADDRESS
wb.SCAA.Range("B" & lastRow + 2).Resize(ContractList.count, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ContractList.keys)

'''' SORT THE CONTRACT LIST A - Z
If ContractList.count <> 1 Then wb.SCAA.Range("B" & lastRow + 2 & ":B" & lastRow + 2 + (ContractList.count - 1)).Sort Key1:=cells(lastRow + 2, 2), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

'''' DEFINE THE LAST ROW IN COLUMN B
lastRowB = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'''' ADD "TOTAL" TO THE SHEET
wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 2, 2) = "TOTAL"

'''' LOOP OVER THE CONTRACT LIST AT BOTTOM AND TOTAL, AND ADD FORMULAS THERE APPRIOPRIATE
For contract_total = lastRow + 2 To lastRowB + 2
    For worktypeHeading = 3 To myRange.columns.count
    Set wtHeading = wb.SCAA.cells(6, worktypeHeading)
    If contract_total = lastRowB + 1 Then Exit For
    If wtHeading.Offset(-1) <> "PROGRESS" Then
        If contract_total <> lastRowB + 2 Then
            wb.SCAA.cells(contract_total, worktypeHeading).formula = "=round(sumif(" & cells(7, 2).address & ":" & cells(lastRow, 2).address & "," & cells(contract_total, 2).address & "," & cells(7, worktypeHeading).address & ":" & cells(lastRow, worktypeHeading).address & "),2)"
            wb.SCAA.cells(contract_total, worktypeHeading).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
        Else
            wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 2, worktypeHeading).formula = "=round(Sum(" & cells(lastRowB - 1, worktypeHeading).address & ":" & cells(lastRowB, worktypeHeading).address & "),2)"
            wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 2, worktypeHeading).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
        End If
    End If
    Next worktypeHeading
Next contract_total

'''' RE-DEFINE THE LAST ROW IN COLUMN B
lastRowB = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'''' ADD TWO HEADINGS
wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 2, 3 + CodeList.count) = "TOTAL ALREADY PAID"
wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 4, 3 + CodeList.count) = "TOTAL CHANGED"

'''' ADD THE FORMULAS TO THE TOTAL ALDREAY PAID, AND TOTAL CHANGED
For worktype_Valuation = CodeList.count + 5 To myRange.columns.count
    worktype_value = wb.SCAA.cells(6, worktype_Valuation)
    If IsEmpty(PHElementTotal(worktype_value)) Or PHElementTotal(worktype_value) = 0 Then
        tempTotal = 0
    Else
        tempTotal = PHElementTotal(worktype_value)
    End If
    If worktype_value <> "Total" Then
        wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 2, worktype_Valuation) = tempTotal
        wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 2, worktype_Valuation).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
        wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 4, worktype_Valuation).formula = "=round(sum(" & cells(lastRowB, worktype_Valuation).address & ":" & cells(lastRowB, worktype_Valuation).address & ",-" & cells(lastRowB + 2, worktype_Valuation).address & "),2)"
        wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 4, worktype_Valuation).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
    Else
        wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 2, worktype_Valuation) = tempTotal
        wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 2, worktype_Valuation).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
        wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 4, worktype_Valuation).formula = "=round(sum(" & cells(lastRowB, worktype_Valuation).address & ":" & cells(lastRowB, worktype_Valuation).address & ",-" & cells(lastRowB + 2, worktype_Valuation).address & "),2)"
        wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 4, worktype_Valuation).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_ ;[Red](#,##0.00)"
    End If
Next worktype_Valuation

Set PHElementTotal = Nothing

'''' CALL THE SORTING SUB ROUTINE
Call sortData(wb.SCAA, 7, (lastRow), (lastCol + 2), False, (lastCol + 1))

'''' LOOP OVER THE ROWS, AND SEPERATE THE ADDRESS INTO SREETS
headingRange = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, lastCol + 2).End(xlUp).Row
For headingID = headingRange To 7 Step -1
    lookupval = wb.SCAA.cells(headingID, lastCol + 2)
    With cells(headingID, lastCol + 2)
        If lookupval <> .Offset(-1) Then
            .EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
            With cells(headingID, 1)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .Font.bold = True
                .Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
                .IndentLevel = 0
            End With
        cells(headingID, 1) = wb.SCAA.cells(headingID + 1, lastCol + 2)
        End If
    End With
Next headingID

'''' ONCE ADDRESS'S HAVE BEEN SORTED AND ADDRESS'S GROUPED INTO STREETS, CLEAR THE STREET HAS PROPERTY NUMBER IN THE LAST 2 COLUMNS
With Union(columns(lastCol + 1), columns(lastCol + 2))
    .ClearContents
End With

'''' REFINE LAST ROW: COLUMN A, AND LAST ROW B: COLUMN B
lastRowB = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'''' APPLY BORDERS TO THE SHEET, AND FORMAT
With wb.SCAA
    With Union(Range(cells(7, 1), cells(lastRow, lastCol)), _
               Range(cells(lastRowB, 2), cells(lastRowB, CodeList.count + 3)), _
               Range(cells(lastRowB, 5 + CodeList.count), cells(lastRowB, lastCol)), _
               Range(cells(lastRow + 2, 2), cells(lastRow + 1 + ContractList.count, 2 + CodeList.count + 1)), _
               Range(cells(lastRow + 2, 5 + CodeList.count), cells(lastRow + 1 + ContractList.count, lastCol)), _
               Range(cells(lastRowB + 2, 5 + CodeList.count), cells(lastRowB + 2, lastCol)), _
               Range(cells(lastRowB + 4, 5 + CodeList.count), cells(lastRowB + 4, lastCol)))
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
            With Range(cells(7, 2), cells(lastRowB, 2))
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
            End With
            With Union(Range(cells(7, 1), cells(lastRow, 1)), _
                       Range(cells(7, 2), cells(lastRow, 2)), _
                       Range(cells(7, 4 + CodeList.count), cells(lastRow, 4 + CodeList.count)))
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
                .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThick
            End With
    End With
End With

'''' LOOP OVER ALL THE ADDRESS'S AND APPLY CONDITIONAL FORMATTING
lastRow = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For address = 7 To lastRow
    If IsEmpty(cells(address, 4 + CodeList.count).value) = False Then
        With wb.SCAA.Range(wb.SCAA.cells(address, 1), wb.SCAA.cells(address, lastCol))
            .FormatConditions.add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & cells(address, 4 + CodeList.count).address(False) & ">1"
            .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(215, 150, 148)
            .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
            .FormatConditions.add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & cells(address, 4 + CodeList.count).address(False) & "<>" & wb.SCAA.cells(address, "AAA").address(False) & ""
            .FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(196, 215, 155)
            .FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End If
Next address

wb.SCAA.Range(columns(2), columns(lastCol)).ColumnWidth = 14

'''' RE-DEFINE THE LAST ROW B
lastRowB = wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'''' LOCK ALL THE CELLS IN SHEET
wb.SCAA.Range(wb.SCAA.cells(1, 1), wb.SCAA.cells(lastRowB + 4, lastCol)).Locked = True

'''' UNLOCK THE PROGRESS COLUMN TO BE ABLE TO CHANGE THE PERCENTAGES
wb.SCAA.Range(wb.SCAA.cells(7, 4 + CodeList.count), wb.SCAA.cells(wb.SCAA.cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 4 + CodeList.count)).Locked = False

'''' SET CONTRACT LIST AND CODE LIST TO NOTHING TO AVOID MEMORY LEAKS
Set ContractList = Nothing
Set CodeList = Nothing
```

Comment: What about sorting?

Comment: Write to an array, do the operations there, and then write back to the sheet?

Comment: @R3uK, the information has already been sorted before this, so it is in the correct order for this. Thanks

Comment: Have you added `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the beginning of the sub (make sure to add `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` to the end)? This will prevent your sheet from updating in real time and make it run a lot faster.

Comment: @SnWhte, yes i have disabled the screen updating before this runs. Thank you

Comment: Will you include your whole sub? Such as where you declare `headingID`.

Comment: @SnWhte. Hi update my OP to include the whole sub.

Comment: Thanks! In a recent project I was trying to run a reverse loop and it was painstakingly slow, so I worked out a way to have it run normally and it ran it in the blink of an eye. Have you tried a _non_ reverse loop for this part to see if that speeds it up?

Comment: @atame are you sure that the slowness is due to the loop that you showed first? There are some nested loops elsewhere and they seems to be huge and involving formulas.

Comment: @SnWhte, Hi, yes I had tried not using a reverse loop, i ran into problems with it identifying the wrong cells, because i was inserting a new row.

Comment: @A.S.H. Hi, I think so, I did just notice there was a Do Events in there, that once removed help increase the speed. I then speed-tested the rest sections of the code and it still appears that the initial loop causing is causing the slowness.

Comment: If you use a `For i = 7 to ...` type of loop, you need to increase `i` by 1 when you insert a new row. I used the following, `If insertRow < i Then i = i + 1` then when it goes to the next `i`, it is aware a new row was added. The problem is a static `lastRow` variable will not work since the total number of rows changes. I just put in 10000 (or any row beyond your data) and put a check in `If cell = vbNullSTring Then Exit For` and you exit the loop when you get to your last row anyways.

Comment: The only two things that may slow down this loop IMO are: 1- repeated comparison of long strings and 2- repeatedly accessing the worksheet (instead of loading the column into VBA array at once). By the way how comes the last column names are "exmaple" and the copied value is "example"? means these are not the real strings here, the actual ones seem to be much longer no?

Comment: by the way I think it is *mandatory* to splt up this routine, it's huge for a single routine. I'm thinking of maintainability here not about speed.

Comment: After some suggestions, I re-coded the section using the worksheet.sumif function. After doing this the speed to run decreased. This routine can be run for different subcontractors, most now taking sub 1 second to complete, there are a couple the take a closer to 10, but a drastic improvement. I will test the other suggestions over the weekend to see if i can better the speed. Thanks!!!

Comment: @A.S.H, I will have a look into the points you have made, and see what I can come up with. I manually changed the road names to example, because of data security. Thanks

Comment: @TheSilkCode, Hi, thanks for the comment, I had noticed that, which is why I used the scripting.dictionary, I copy the range data into memory and process it there, which in the test i have run, drastically reduce the processing time. Thanks

Comment: @atame , Glad figured out a solution- just a quick note for you to remember going forward:
The reason your original code is so slow is because of the large number of times using range data.... in general, ranges ranges are slow- finding them, setting them, reading in or changing from a cell, etc... What you should instead do is use arrays- read all the range data into an array as a single block, do your tests, manipulation, etc. on the data, then export as a single block (if possible) back to a worksheet... Switching from using ranges to arrays can speed up macros by ~93% in my tests!...

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but you have a LOT of variables defined as the variant type:

For example, in the declaration line you have:

Dim lastRowWIR, lastRowPH, lastRowCODES, lastRow, lastCol As Long

Here, only lastCol is defined as Long, all the rest are variant type, that's a VBA quirk.

Redefining all as set types where possible may help your process speed.